# Can I undo 'Mark as Deployed' option in ReadyRoll?

Tags: redgate, sqlmigrations

I marked 2 scripts as deployed and checked in my changes to TFS. Can I undo this in the ReadyRoll project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click *Mark as Deployed*, ReadyRoll inserts a row into the `[__MigrationLog]` table within the target database in order to prevent the script from being re-executed.

In order to undo this, simply delete the record from the target database, e.g.

`DELETE FROM [dbo].[__MigrationLog]
WHERE script_filename = '0001_20161125-1446_username.sql'`

If you have many servers to undo 'mark as deployed':

- If the script is a Migration, [generate a new guid](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx) and replace the value within the `<Migration ID="{guid}"/>` metadata (which can be found within the header of your script).
- If the script is a Programmable Object, then simply add a make a trivial change to the file (e.g. add some white space). This is enough to trigger a change to the checkum, causing the script to be re-deployed.